# Where to define a method that is used only inside __init__ and must not be called anywhere else?

Tags: python

```
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = None
        self.run_equation()

    def run_equation(self):
        # it runs through a formula then assigns the end value to length
        self.length = 50 # 50 for example
```

Now I want to populate a list with few `Line` objects.
The thing is I dont want `run_equation()` to be called ever again becouse I allready assigned the attribute inside `__init__`, and it's value must not be changed.

What approaches should I follow, or do I have to stick this mind and simply not calling the method from the instance?

PS: Didn't find much on google or I just don't know how to search for this question.

Comment: Btw. it’s *“length”*.

Comment: @poke Thanks I have eddited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python tries to hide methods and data that start with 2 underbars from outside users. Its not perfect, but the underbars tell programmers that you really don't want them to fiddle with them. Add a property to get a read only view of length, and I think you'll have what you want:

```
class Line(object):
    @property
    def length(self):
        """The length of the line"""
        return self.__length

    def __init__(self):
        """Create a line"""
        self.__length = None
        self.__run_equation()

    def _run_equation(self):
        self.__length = 50
```

A trial run shows limited access

```
>>> from line import Line
>>> l=Line()
>>> l.length
50
>>> l.length = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> l.__length = 1
>>> l.__run_equation()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Line' object has no attribute '__run_equation'
>>> l.length
50

>>> help(Line)
Help on class Line in module line:

class Line(__builtin__.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self)
 |      Create a line
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  length
 |      The length of the line
```

Answer (score 1):

If there’s only a single place where this is used—in `__init__`—then you don’t need a separate method to begin with. Just put the contents of that method into your `__init__` directly:

```
class Line (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.length = 50
```

Comment: I'm not trying to do `get/set` stuff here, the method that assigns length picks it from some math equation that is actualy running logic. The code is example.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to define a function inside another function, and it will only be visible from the containing function:

```
def example():
    def pointless_function():
        print("Why do I exist, again?")
    pointless_function()

example()
pointless_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of it once you're done:

```
class Line(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = None
        self.assign_value_to_length()
        self.assign_value_to_length = None

    def assign_value_to_length(self):
        self.length = 50
```

This isn't very good practice, though. Instead, I'd just add an assertion:

```
    def assign_value_to_length(self):
        assert self.length is None
        self.length = 50
```

Comment: You can still call `Line.assign_value_to_length(line_instance)`.  There isn't any foolproof method to stop someone from doing "bad things" to your classes.

Comment: @metatoaster You are correct. Further, someone could just go and `line_instance.length = 42`. There's no way to keep someone from doing weird things to Python objects, so the best we can do is sanity checks and testing. The assertion would at least catch the use of that unbound method, assuming no other shenanigans.